# JavaScript performance while appending a large number of children to a large number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have many select inputs on a page (96 or 384). Each has an extensive list of options - almost 1000. As a result the size of the page is between 4-8MB (1-4MB compressed). I decided to make to page load faster by putting list of options just once and then add it to each input with JavaScript.

Unfortunately, the browser either needs a lots of time to finish the task (~3 minutes on FF 10) or hangs (Chrome 17). I tried to accomplish the task with jQuery and pure JS. No difference at all.

Is the task feasible? What should I know to write fast and efficient JavaScript?

[image: Screenshot]

Edit: I put all the options to a single string and use innerHTML to put it to the select input. Thanks for such a quick response.

Edit2: I generate elements the way suggested by Diodeus. However, I load options when the select element is in focus (thanks rlemon). I believe all the answers are very helpful and might be valuable for anyone having similar problem. Thank you all.

Comment: Maybe you should show your JS code, so we can have a look at it, but generally you maybe sould change your interface and use just a single select from which the values get added to a (readonly) input field besides instead of having many large selects.

Comment: Maybe you should have your inputs onfocus load the list of options... this way each input *will* take slightly longer to load but the overall page should be speedy.

Comment: Another good point. Thank you rlemon.

Comment: remember that adding additional scripts / plugins to your page will increase the overall size and therefore slow down your page load. If you are not already using jQuery I do not suggest using it for this purpose. There are many light-weight AJAX and XHR libs/objects out there for you to use that don't come with an additional ~30-50kb of overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build up your HTML as a string or single object an inject it all into that page in one go. DOM re-writes are slow because document re-flows must be calculated for each insert.

Comment: this could also be achieved with [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DocumentFragment). document Fragments allow you to store and work with the elements as if they were DOM elements but does not trigger reflow. Once you have built up your tree you can simply append the DF to the DOM.

Comment: As a side note using an array and `push()`-ing all the strings makes a big difference on old browsers (specifically IE < 9) if that's of any concern to you..

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to append the children separately? Simply wrap the whole list with the options in another element and append that one. This should be much faster since it will be just one operation instead of 1000.

Comment: I put all the options to a single string and use innerHTML to put it to the select input. I should have said it in my post. Anyway, thanks for such a quick answer :).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use ajax. Replace standard input selects with 3rd party combobox E.g: Jquery UI Combobox. First you load all empty comboboxes. It items will be loaded as soon as use click to open drop down list.

You can do it quite easy with jquery and jquery UI.

Answer (score 1):

It's faster to have everything loaded by default on the HTML than using JS to append thousands of elements.

Your server gives you a guarantee of quality/speed the user's computer won't.

Comment: downloading 4-5mb is going to take a while either way, an appropriate solution would be to dynamically load the options based on the users focus.