# Setting jQuery data on a div when appending it as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I am creating a jQuery plugin which generates a lot of `divs`.
Initially i was creating all the elements using `append` function as below.

```
var myObject= $('<div></div>').addClass('myobjectname');
parentObject.append(myObject);
```

I have lot of elements created like this and also each have different `data` associated with them using `myObject.data('mykey',ajavascriptobject);`
But later on, when I started reading more about optimization of jQuery, I understood that DOM manipulation functions like `append` are very costly when it comes to performance.

Now, I am trying to create the whole `div` structure as string and then append it as a whole to the parent DOM object which is supposed to very much improve the performance.

```
var i=0;
var myBigString = [];
myBigString[i++] = "<div class=\"myobjectname\">";
myBigString[i++] = "my content";
myBigString[i++] = "</div>";
parentObject.append(myBigString.join(''));
```

I am using the `data()` function to store details about each object to later access it (when clicking/mouseover etc). But now, since I am creating a string of the whole `div` structure,

**How can I associate the `data` to the elements if I am creating them as a string and later appending it to DOM?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
<div data-datum-name="your data string"></div>
```

For objects:

```
<div data-datum-name=' + JSON.stringify(yourObject) + '></div>
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/BxdUN/2/).

Comment: > thanks a lot!.. so will I be able to retrieve the object as is when the `data` function is called on the element? Also, just to confirm, my object has sub objects. Will this work in that situation? lastly, since I am going to give a considerable effort modifying my code, do you think this will really improve the performance?

Comment: Yes, to get all data: `$('selector').data()`. It should be faster - each DOM modification requires that the document re-flow must be recalculated, which can be a bottleneck: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9467577/187954 You might also just `myBigString.push(anotherString)` instead of your `i` variable.